# What is a good gitignore to use with Codeblocks C++ Projects?

Tags: c++, git, codeblocks, gitignore

This is what I have so far:

```
obj/
bin/
```

Anything else?

Comment: https://www.gitignore.io/api/codeblocks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this:

```
*.layout
*.depend
bin/
obj/
```

See:
https://www.gitignore.io/api/codeblocks

Comment: Due to an incorrect pull request merged on Sep 2, 2018, the gitignore at that link ignores the cbp file itself! That is not a generated filetype--it contains all the information about files to include and compile! Your answer itself provides a better gitignore, and I've submitted a pull request reflecting that to https://github.com/dvcs/gitignore/pulls (to correct the issue on gitignore.io).

Answer (score 3):

GitHub has some gitignore files to get a project started. For a C++-Project they have the following `.gitignore` file: ([C++.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/C%2B%2B.gitignore))

```
# Prerequisites
*.d

# Compiled Object files
*.slo
*.lo
*.o
*.obj

# Precompiled Headers
*.gch
*.pch

# Compiled Dynamic libraries
*.so
*.dylib
*.dll

# Fortran module files
*.mod
*.smod

# Compiled Static libraries
*.lai
*.la
*.a
*.lib

# Executables
*.exe
*.out
*.app
```

You can find the whole repository with many other languages here: https://github.com/github/gitignore